# Packaging local ruby gems using Bundler?

Tags: rubygems, jruby, bundler, warbler, gemfile

I have a project that I'm working on that uses a gem we've created internally.  It's not hosted on rubygems.org or github.  But we do have it in our repository and in a path on our local machine.

In our Gemfile, we have something similar to this:

```
gem "our-custom-gem", :path => "/path-to/our-custom-gem"
```

We're trying to package all our gems so we can use the warbler gem to create a .war file in order to deploy using jRuby.

We'd like to be able to run something like "bundle install" or "bundle install --local" to make sure all the gems are installed.  Then have bundler take all the dependencies specified in our Gemfile put them in vendor/bundle using the "bundle package" command.

But based on this link (http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-package.1.html), it looks like bundler cannot package gems specified using :path or :git as the source.

Has anyone found a way around this?

How do you "bundle package" gems that are local and that are not part of a git repo or available on rubygems.org?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Breaking news!**

> Since Bundler 1.2, the bundle package command can also package :git
> and :path dependencies besides .gem files. This needs to be explicitly
> enabled via the --all option. Once used, the --all option will be
> remembered.

Documentation:https://bundler.io/guides/git.html

Answer (score 0):

Judging from this [pull requerst](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/67), it's a feature planned for 1.1.

One of the core developers gave [this workaround](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/67#issuecomment-154741), though:

```
cd vendor/git
git clone git://github.com/foo/foo.git
```

> Then, in your Gemfile, gem "foo", :path => "vendor/git/foo".

There's been some work to fix the issue on [this branch](https://github.com/benhamill/bundler/pull/1).

Good luck!